# guaranteeing to wake up all threads and only once per each

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I found a bug in my program, that the same thread is awoke twice taking the opportunity for another thread to run, thus causing unintended behaviours. It is required in my program that all threads waiting should run exactly once per turn. This bug happens because I use semaphores to make the threads wait. With a semaphore initialized with count 0, every thread calls `down` to the semaphore at the start of its infinite loop, and the main thread calls `up` in a for loop `NThreads` (the number of threads) times. Occasionally the same thread takes the `up` call twice and the problem arises.

What is the way to deal with this problem properly? Is using condition variables and broadcasting a way to do this? Will it guarantee that every thread is awoke once and only once? What are other good ways possible?

Comment: Your question seems vague to me, but in general, yes, condition variables are used to test if a piece of code is allowed to run.

Comment: I don't believe condition variables will help you by themselves, you can wake one thread or wake all threads but the waker can't know or control which blocking thread will be unblocked.  Unfortunately I think you need one mutex for each thread to control the wake / block states in the exact manner you require.

Comment: Down vote because you tagged c and c++ preventing any non trivial reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, use an array of semaphores, one for each thread.  If you want the array of threads to run once only, send one unit to each semaphore.  If you want the threads to all run exactly N times, send N units to each semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, you could use `WaitForMultipleObjects` to select a ready thread from the threads that have not been run in the current Nthread iterations.

Each thread should have a "ready" event to signal when it is ready, and a "wake" event to wait on after it has signaled its "ready" event.

At the start of your main thread loop (1st of NThreads iteration), call `WaitForMultipleObjects` with an array of your NThreads "ready" events.

Then set the "wake" event of the thread corresonding to the "ready" event returned by `WaitForMultipleObjects`, and remove it from the array of "ready" handles. That will guaranty that the thread that has already been run won't be returned by `WaitForMultipleObjects` on the next iteration.

Repeat until the last iteration, where you will call `WaitForMultipleObjects` with an array of only 1 thread handle (I think this will work as if you called WaitForSingleObject).

Then repopulate the array of NThreads "ready" events for the next new Nthreads iterations.